How detailed should I be with client quotes when competitors might under quote to get a client?
The idea is that if I make a quote with all the prices of components and labor, the client may take that quote to my competitor, who may under quote to get the job. I would really prefer to have a system that can easily build a quote/invoice based on our price list and be able to add/remove details to my liking.
A client getting multiple quotes for a job and/or sharing those quotes with competitors is normal (previous questions 1,2,3). While there is a downside to sharing a quote with a competitor (they might take their really low price and increase it) I don't think that is a common thought with my clients, they just want the cheapest quote to get the job done.
So how much detail should I include in the quotes? I want to include labor cost and any components with the markup to accurately represent the job.
At my current company, they don't like sharing too much detail because some components are marked up higher than most places (we either have to go and fetch it or hold the stock in inventory) and a contractor without our overhead could easily reduce their prices to get the job, arguably by using cheaper or inferior components and by having less overhead.
My thought would be to adjust our margins to compete and try to market the benefits of our services and component choices, while including as much info as I reasonably can. Or I could leave that level of detail for the invoice after the work is done and do a very simple quote as an estimate. Would this open me up to clients challenging my prices and end up being way too much work than its worth?

How does the level of detail influence the likelihood of a competitor beating you with a lower price? If you omit all details and just quote a total price of 5000, what's stopping a competitor from offering 4800?

It was a different context, but when I got two quotes for construction, I went with the detailed one, because I could see that they weren't forgetting important parts.

If a competitor under-quotes, that's their problem. Either they will be working for less profit than you consider acceptable, or they'll do a shoddy job or have to come back with a request for more money; the latter will hurt their reputation and make it easier for you to get the next contract.
Be aware of what your competition charges. But don't get into a race to the bottom. Charge a fair price, and if folks won't pay it maybe you are going after the wrong customers or are in the wrong business.

If your clients are taking detailed quotes to your competitors in order to get lower prices, you are going after the wrong clients.
In any market, of 10 people who want your services, only 2-3 can actually pay for them and perhaps only 1 will actually buy. Thus, it is important to qualify your clients before doing detailed quotes. Ask hard questions about their ability to pay your prices AND what they want in terms of quality, service, and reliability. "You can find others who are cheaper, but they are cheaper in quality and service."
Having said all that, it may be possible to do two different quotes, one highly detailed internal quote and one with far less detail that is given to the client. (And if you have the right software, the one for the client can be generated from the internal quote.)

Are you selling the value of your services or the efficiency of your distribution? In other words is your company just another "Do you want fries with that" mindset or can you do something better than other people?
By focusing your quotes / proposals on what makes you better than the next company, you give the prospect a reason to consider you for more than price. In this case focus on the details of the services. The more detail the better (within reason). Don't assume the prospect already knows what you will provide.
This detail is what separates you from the competetion. If it isn't listed, then is it being provided? That is why you get to be the "Experts".
If price is the only thing, then you best be cheaper because you are more effiencent than the rest. Then you can focus on the price of the widgets.
It is eaiser to review detailed quotes. An engaged prospect that wants to understand is fine.
It is hard to challenge detailed quotes. When they do, remind them: Good, Fast, Cheap - pick two.
To your point about:

At my current company, they don't like sharing too much detail because some components are marked up higher than most places (we either have to go and fetch it or hold the stock in inventory) and a contractor without our overhead could easily reduce their prices to get the job, arguably by using cheaper or inferior components and by having less overhead.

Please lose that logic because it is a race to the bottom. Assuming the inventory isn't stale or exessive, having what is needed to do the upcoming work saves an incredible amount of labor. That is not including current supply chain issues. Unless no one is being paid while not producing (100% commission sales and all outside contractor labor). Having what is needed, is smart. If the cost difference is that much between you the competetion, something else is up.
